# using http2 with okhttp in android, why 20 stream is created for 20 request

Tags: android, okhttp, http2

Using okhttp 3.8.1

I use okhttp http2 to request for 20 same pictures at the same time using multiple thread with same okhttpclient.

I use tcp dump to capture the traffic. Found that there are still 20 tcp stream, with one much larger, and the other 19 smaller.

My question is what are these 19 streams for. Or am I using ok http in the wrong way?

```
    up      down    count 
    2510    56320   1
    352     3492    19
```

my code is something like this

```
    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        runTest(urls[i], client);
        }
...
    private void runTest(...)
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url(url)
                                .build();
                        try {
                            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                            result = response.body().string();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you able to think how "runTest(urls[i], client);" result ?

Comment: @Sree I remember that okhttp recommend to use same client for different requests? no ?

Comment: http://square.github.io/okhttp/ check this

Comment: @Sree sorry, still don't get yout point. But the document of OkHttpClient says "OkHttpClients should be shared
OkHttp performs best when you create a single OkHttpClient instance and reuse it for all of your HTTP calls."

Comment: I can only guess here, you can verify this by looking into the tcp dump. One connection actually loads the image, the others will just check if the cached version is still up to date.

Comment: @Henry as it's http2 over tls, so I can't look into the content of the tcp dump traffic. And besides, i'v disable the cache by setting builder.cache(null);

Comment: In HTTP/2, a request/response corresponds to one stream. Do you mean tcp connection by "20 tcp stream"?

Comment: @laike9m "20 tcp stream" is what i see in tcpdump, I understand this to be 20 tcp connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer lies in the discussions here https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3442

in brief, when the concurrent requests starts, there's not a usable tcp channel yet, so okhttp create new tcp channel for each request(20). after the first one is establish, with the coalescing mechanism, the other requests will abandon the tcp channel it create and use the first established one.